# How to set up a gitconfig file

Tags: git, github, git-config

Trying to set up some aliases for git config, i know i can do it through terminal but I would like to setup a git config file as given here. http://gitimmersion.com/lab_11.html. But I dont understand exactly what i need to do, i have tried saving that exact text in a file ".gitconfig" through sublime 2 but it does not work. Where exactly is the home directory of git? I have used "which git" in terminal to get the path "/usr/local/git/bin/git". Placing the file in /usr/local/git/bin does nothing, ive tried several other directories to no avail.

Comment: *Add the following to the .gitconfig file in your $HOME directory.* You probably want `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: It refers to your home directory...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That post makes it clear:

> Add the following to the .gitconfig file in your $HOME directory.

That means `$HOME/.gitconfig` (e.g. /home/felipec/.gitconfig).

But precisely for this reason is why the `--edit` option was added:

```
git config --global --edit
```

Now you don't have to know or care where is the file, just edit it.